# How to average "Odds likelyhood" when probabilities from multiple models are involved?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood, odds-ratio, odds

I am trying to understand a problem confusion.

Say, we have two models (m1 and m2) that predicts probability of "rain" on a particular day.

If I am trying to calculate average odds of rain, which one is the appropriate method, and why?

```
# Method 01 - we have probability of rain from model m1 and m2 as
p(rain_m1) = 0.55 , p(no_rain_m1) = 0.45
so, odds(rain vs. no_rain)m1  = 0.55/0.45 = 1.2222

p(rain_m2) = 0.75 , p(no_rain_m2) = 0.25
so, odds(rain vs. no_rain)m2  = 0.75/0.25 = 3

# so, the average odds of rain vs. no rain
(3 + 1.222)/2 = 2.1111


# another method to calculate odds (rain vs. no rain)
avg_rain (m1, m2) = 0.65 , avg_no_rain (m1, m2) = 0.35
avg_odds = 0.65/0.35 = 1.8571
```

Thanks,